# How to get a value inside a cell from a changing cell address

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

Let's say I have Column A that has a bunch of numbers. In B1 we have `"=A1"`
How can I get B2 to be `="B1"+6` so that B2 will have the value of A7
and B3 will have `B2+6` so that it will have the value of A13 ... etc

I tried to google but I couldnt really articulate what I wanted.

Comment: `=INDEX(A:A,(ROW($Z1)-1)*6+1)`

Comment: `=OFFSET($A$1,ROW()*6-6,0)`

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome just a caveat to that formula.  Offset is volatile, while Index is not.  Volatility can add unnecessary load to the calcs if overused.

Comment: @ScottCraner You are right. I just provide an option. Who knows what's OP's final goal.

Comment: @ScottCraner it still doesn't work for me. If cell B1=A1, then (ROW($B1)-1)*6+1 should return 7 if I am understanding the command properly, it is not, it's returning 97... I'm really confused

Comment: no, you put the formula in B1 and copy it down as is.  Leave the `$Z1` as is.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in B1 and copy it down:

```
=INDEX(A:A,(ROW($Z1)-1)*6+1)
```

[image]